# VIDEOJS: playing a pre-roll add before each playlist item

Tags: node.js, video, video.js, google-ima

I'm using the videojs-playlist plugin along with Google's videojs-ima plugin. Everything works swimmingly except I am only getting a preload ad before the first video. I want one before *each* video in the playlist.
Basic setup is boilerplate, but for reference:

```
this.player = videojs('currentvideo', { autoplay : true, fluid : true });
this.player.playlist(this.playlist);
this.player.playlist.autoadvance(5);

const skippable_linear = {google's test ad};
const options = {
    id: 'currentvideo',
    adTagUrl: skippable_linear,
    debug : true
};

this.player.ima(
    options
);
this.player.ima.requestAds();
```

I have tried various ways of manually calling ads from inside an 'ended' event handler, such as calling `requestAds` again:

```
const _this = this;
this.player.on( 'ended', function(){
    /* some other stuff */
    _this.player.ima.requestAds();
});
```

This *does* play an ad where I want it, but

1. this breaks playlist's 'autoadvance' setting (next video doesn't start playing when the ad is finished), and
2. this puts the player into "ad display" mode (scrubber is unavailable, etc).

Is there a simple way to just say, "play an ad now" programmatically? I've tried, without joy, to use all of the seemingly applicable methods exposed by both the ima plugin and the contrib-ads plugin it relies on. I'll admit here that this is the first time I've ever had to deal with videos that run ads, so I'm kind of a noob.

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to do the same thing. Just like you I failed when calling `player.ima.requestAds()` on events. I dug deeper and the best I could come up with is what I share bellow.

According to the videojs-ima [API](https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima/wiki/API-Docs#setcontentwithadtag-contentsrc-adtag-playonload-) you have to use the `setContentWithAdTag` method instead of whatever you are using to switch the player content. In our case it is the `player.playlist.next` method.

I combined the code found in the [videojs-ima examples](https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima/blob/master/examples/playlist/ads.js) with the original `playlist.next` to write my own `next`.

Then quite brutally I overrode the original plugin method.

Here's the code:

```
player.playlist(myPlayilst);
player.playlist.autoadvance(2);
player.playlistUi(); //videojs-playlist-ui

player.ima({
    id: 'video5',
    adTagUrl: 'thy adserver request'
});

//override playlist.next
player.playlist.next = function(){

    var nextIndex = 0,
        playlist = this.player_.playlist,
        list = this.player_.playlist();

//everything below is copied directly from the original `next` (except for the "//load with ad")

    // Repeat
    if (playlist.repeat_) {
        nextIndex = playlist.currentIndex_ + 1;
        if (nextIndex > list.length - 1) {
            nextIndex = 0;
        }

    } else {
        // Don't go past the end of the playlist.
        nextIndex = Math.min(playlist.currentIndex_ + 1, list.length - 1);
    }

    // Make the change
    if (nextIndex !== playlist.currentIndex_) {

    //load with ad
        this.player_.playlist.currentItem(nextIndex);
        this.player_.ima.setContentWithAdTag(
            this.player_.playlist.currentItem(),
            null,
            true);

        this.player_.ima.requestAds();
    /////

        return list[playlist.currentItem()];
    }
}
```

You will probably need to override other methods that change the current playback, like `playlist.previous`.

I use `videojs-playlist-ui` so in my case it was neccessary to change the onclick handler called `switchPlaylistItem_`. I used some good old brute force to do that like this:

```
videojs.getComponent('PlaylistMenuItem').prototype.switchPlaylistItem_ = function(e){
    this.player_.playlist.currentItem(this.player_.playlist().indexOf(this.item));
    this.player_.ima.setContentWithAdTag(
        this.player_.playlist.currentItem(),
        null,
        true);
    this.player_.ima.requestAds();
};
```

`PlaylistMenuItem`'s prototype should be changed ***before*** initializing the player.

This solution works, but it feels hacky, so if anyone can come up with something cleaner, please share!

Comment: Ooh, this looks promising! I ended up just making my own playlist (discarding the playlist plugin), and calling this.player.dispose() after each video and then recreating the player. Will look at this. My solution is non-ideal.

Comment: Honestly, I think it's better to write your own playlist. The best way to go would be to fork videojs-playlist, and change `next` and `prev` to your purpose.

Comment: By the way - sorry to be such a point-hunter - but could you upvote or accept my answer by any chance? I'd be grateful :)

Comment: Took 5 years, but upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up forking `videojs-playlist`, and adding the option to override the `player.src` method. Feel free to use it:

[fw-videojs-playlist](https://github.com/filmweb-open/fw-videojs-playlist)

Details on how to use it are all in the github readme (including an example with `ima.setContentWithAdTag`)

Answer (score 0):

I could do this successfully with

```
videojs-ima: 2.2.0
videojs-playlist: 5.1.0
```

You just have to listen to the `beforeplaylistitem`

Something like this works:

```
player.on('beforeplaylistitem', (event, item) => {
    const adtag = 'youradtag';
    player.ima.setContentWithAdTag(item.sources, adtag);
    player.ima.requestAds();
});
```

Note that requestAds() will only work after ads have been set for the first time, otherwise you'll get requestAds() is undefined.